# What are the disadvantages of using let instead of var in ES6+?

Tags: javascript

I heard that let is the new var and I'm aware of the advantages.
Still, I'm curious if it has any disadvantages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword

Comment: you need just to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Other than (lack of) universal browser support?